# Gremlin: How to reference for loop variable within query?

Tags: gremlin

reI'm stuck with a gremlin query to assign `rank` values to nodes based on a sorted list of keys passed to the query as a parameter.
Each node identified by "uniqueId" values should be assigned a rank based on order of occurrence in the reranked array.

This works:

```
reranked = [uniqueId1, uniqueId2, uniqueId3]
v.outE.as('e').inV.filter{it.key == reranked[2]}.back('e').sideEffect{it.rank = 2}
```

But this doesn't (replacing int with for-loop variable):

```
reranked = [uniqueId1, uniqueId2, uniqueId3]
for (i in 1..reranked.size())
v.outE.as('e').inV.filter{it.key == reranked[i]}.back('e').sideEffect{it.rank = i}
```

Do you know why this doesn't work? I'd also be happy for simpler ideas to reach the same goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using Groovy's `eachWithIndex` like:

```
reranked = [uniqueId1, uinqueId2, uniqueId3]
reranked.eachWithIndex{uniqueId, idx -> v.outE.as('e').inV.has('key', uniqueId).back('e').sideEffect{it.rank = idx} }
```

I have used Gremlin's `has` step above because it's much more efficient than `filter` in case of simple property look-up.

Comment: Great, this is a nice improvement over my solution! And do you know why the loop variable `i` doesn't make it into the functions scope in my question?

Comment: No, I don't think I know an exact answer for that. But I have never seen a for loop being used in Gremlin constructs. Especially since we already have each{} and eachWithIndex{} iterators.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like I found a solution, maybe clumsy but hey, it works!

```
c=0
v.as('st').outE.as('e').inV.filter{it.key == reranked[c]}.back('e').sideEffect{
    it.rank = reranked.size() - c }.outV.loop('st'){ c++ < so.size() }
```

I will still accept another answer if there's a fix for above situation and perhaps a more elgant approach to the solution.